# Dynamic text box not being updated in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield

I'm having a problem with updating a dynamic text field in AS3. This is the code:

```
public class LabelFormFieldMC extends GenericFormFieldMC {
    private var displayLabel:TextField;
    public function LabelFormFieldMC(formField : FormField) {
        super(formField);
        setupLabel();
    }
    override public function setFieldValue() : void {
        trace("LabelFormFieldMC sez: I am trying to set to value " + field.getFieldValue());
        var fieldValue:String = field.getFieldValue();
        var embeddedFonts : Array = Font.enumerateFonts(false);
        embeddedFonts.sortOn("fontName", Array.CASEINSENSITIVE);
        trace("\n----- Enumerate Fonts -----");
        for(var i : int = 0;i < embeddedFonts.length;i++) {
            trace(embeddedFonts[i].fontName);
        }
        trace("---------------------------\n");
        trace("LabelFormFieldMC sez: My field value is not null " + (fieldValue!=null));
        if( fieldValue != null){
            displayLabel.text = fieldValue;
        } else {
            displayLabel.text = "";
        }

        trace("LabelFormFieldMC sez: My text value is " + displayLabel.text);
    }
    override public function setLabelWidth(labelWidth : Number):void {
        super.setLabelWidth(labelWidth);
        displayLabel.x = label.x + label.width + GAP_SIZE;
    }
    private function setupLabel():void{
        var tFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        tFormat.font = "Arial";
        tFormat.size = 14;
        tFormat.bold = true;
        tFormat.align = TextFormatAlign.LEFT;   

        displayLabel = new TextField();
        displayLabel.type = TextFieldType.DYNAMIC;
        displayLabel.defaultTextFormat = tFormat;
        displayLabel.border = true;
        displayLabel.x = label.x + label.width + GAP_SIZE;
        displayLabel.selectable =  false;
        displayLabel.height = 20;
        displayLabel.width = 301;
        this.addChild(displayLabel);
    }
}
```

Please excuse all of the trace statements. Things like the static GAP_SIZE and so on are declared in the GenericFormFieldMC that this inherits from.

My font is embedded when I look at the trace output for the enumerated fonts, and this code works the first time that the field value is updated. The trace statement at the end of the setFieldFalue() function is telling me that the text is set to the right thing, but it isn't displaying.

I've done a lot of searching on this, and I still can't work out what's going on here. I've worked around this in other areas of my code by destroying the object and recreating it, but I'd like to know why I can't just update the text. I've tried not using a text format and making displayLabel.embedFonts = false, but that hasn't helped. If anyone has any ideas I will be very grateful.

Comment: You should be using embedFonts = true, actually. I don't see it in your code.

Comment: Ok, I had read somewhere that embedFonts = true was the default, but it seems not. So I've added that, and it still doesn't work. I've also tried embedding the font in my library, exporting it for actionscript, creating a Font object with that class and then using that class with the text format. That isn't working either!

Comment: Have also added a trace statement when setFieldValue() is called to confirm what the current text stored in the textField is. This shows that the correct text is being stored (e.g. it is the same as the previously failed update).

Comment: Have you tried with another font family? A few weeks ago I had a very similar issue - I could set the text on the timeline, I couldn't set it from a class despite the fact that the font was embedded. I could retrieve the "textfield.text" just ok but nothing appeared in the field. It turned out to be the font itself.

Comment: Tried it with Times Roman (again, embedding and exporting the font etc). I can see it is applied on some of the other text fields that don't change after the initial value is set, and I can see the font in the enumerated list, but I'm still not getting anything in the text field that changes. I don't get anything if I take the defaultTextFormat off either and just leave it with the system font. I appreciate the suggestions, I'm a little frustrated!

Comment: Try to do this: tFormat.font = new YourEmbeddedFontLinkageName().fontName; Does it change anything at all?

Comment: No, I've been doing that already. Sorry, that was my poorly-explained exporting the font, creating the font object then using that in the defaultTextFormat bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you have embedded all needed glyphs from that font. I have made this working with dynamic text like this:

```
var f: Font;

f = new FONT_ARIAL_REGULAR; // embed font class name.. 

txtFormat = new TextFormat();
txtFormat.font = f.fontName;            
txtFormat.color = 0x000000; // Black text :)
txtFormat.size = 12;
txtFormat.align = TextFormatAlign.LEFT;

textField = new TextField();

textField.defaultTextFormat = txtFormat;
textField.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
textField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
textField.multiline = false;
textField.wordWrap = false;
textField.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
textField.condenseWhite = true;
textField.embedFonts = true;
textField.gridFitType = GridFitType.PIXEL;
```

If i remember right.. the **condenseWhite = true** was important to set and does some tricks.. and also you should always take font name from class.. not from hardcoded string.

Also.. make it simple when debugging things:

- make sure your textfield is really visible and there is no other elements hiding it
- comment out all extra code or test component in simple environment like new, plain flash file

not doubting your skills.. just make sure nothing else is wrong in your code :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice - turns out you should totally have been doubting my skills on this one! It turned out that at some point I started adding two of everything to the internal array of formfields. The display was showing the second of these versions, but the update only got applied to the first (unseen) version. Your advice to take it into a more straightforward project was extremely helpful, which is why I'm marking yours as the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check this small trick. Just embed the font you need in a dummy text box on stage and hide it and proceed your way